# A scifi book about a boy raised to fight in a war by playing a realtime strategy game

Tags: story-identification

Back in the early 2000's, I read a scifi book that I'm now trying to recall. I picked it up in a public school library. The book might have been published in the 80's or 90's. Here's what I remember...

The story followed a remarkably intelligent boy. He was raised in an isolated environment largely by some kind of AI that, as best as I can remember, could appear holographically either maternal or paternal, as was needed. His purpose was to settle a territory dispute by defeating similarly raised opponents from other nations by playing a violent game with them... The book was a bit older than modern video games, though - I think the book compared this game to chess, instead of to other video games. The game sort of resembled a modern 3rd person real-time strategy game, in which units were commanded from above, and moved and fought on their commanders' behalf. I remember the character being shocked when the units in the game actually bled and died.

The boy was assisted by two other characters, one male and one female. The other male character had significant physical disabilities that weren't evident when the characters met each other virtually. All three had slightly different roles in ensuring they won the games. None of them were supposed to leave their habitats, but they tended to sneak away together...

In the end, the boy won the "war," and demanded the disputed territory for himself and his two friends. In the epilogue, I can remember the boy trying to determine the RPM of a nearby aircraft's engine by listening to it, but realizing it was a skill he had lost from not practicing it since winning the game.

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate. Please do not feel that this is a censure, or that this is a bad question. It is merely one we have had before, and we want to ensure that they're linked in the system. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be [*Virtual War*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/87427.Virtual_War) by Gloria Skurzynski as per [YA dystopia novel of battle school with unusual military control scheme](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110234/ya-dystopia-novel-of-battle-school-with-unusual-military-control-scheme).

[image: Front cover of Virtual War]

> Imagine a life of virtual reality -- a childhood contained in a controlled environment, with no human contact or experiences outside of the world of computer-generated images. Corgan has been genetically engineered by the Federation for quick reflexes, high intelligence, and physical superiority. Everything Corgan is, everything he has ever seen or done, was to prepare him for one moment: a bloodless, computer-controlled virtual war. When Corgan meets his two fellow warriors, he begins to question the Federation. Now Corgan must decide where his loyalties lie, what he's willing to fight for, and exactly what he wants in return. His decisions will affect not only these three virtual warriors, but all the people left on earth.

From [this review on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/129831057?book_show_action=true):

> 14 year old Corgan has sepent his whole life in his Box where he has been raised by Mendor, a computer program who appears as both loving Mother and stern Father. He has been genetically engineered to have fast reflexes so he and his team can win the virtual war to settle the claims to ownership of the Isles of Hiva. Sharla, also 14, is a code breaking expert and Mutant Brig has a genius intellect and is the Strategist. Corgan has never has physical contact with another human being until Sharla breaks the code to open his door without anyone knowing. The three meet and begin to explore the domed city and decide how they should proceed. They discover secrets and must learn to trust one another. When they are caught outside their Boxes, they are placed in Reprimand. Brig decides to ask for a reward if they win the War. This motivates the teammates to try their hardest but Corgan especially is sickened by what he sees in the war practice. When the day of the War arrives, each of the three must makes decisions that have far-reaching consequences. I didn't like the book as much as I thought I would. Sharla seemed a little too scheming and dishonest. It felt like she was manipulating Corgan who was so innocent. I found out I was right after I finished the sequel.

Other reviews mention him being traumatized by seeing the virtual deaths of soldiers, and that Brig is physically disabled.

Comment: That's it. Mendor's name stuck out at me almost instantly. In fact, it was distantly remembering Mendor that had me thinking about this book... Thank you!